# DNS Server in c/c++ for windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, dns

Is there any DNS Server written in C/C++ which can be compiled using Visual studio on Windows?
I have found many DNS servers, but all of them seem to run only on Linux or require a MinGW compiler.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need to compile *any* server? Why don't you use binaries?

Comment: Yes it is a project requirement that I compile. I cannot just use an exe, which would be obviously much simpler

Comment: Do you realize *any* Windows Server comes with an optionally installable/configurable [DNS server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_DNS#DNS_server) already packaged with it? (or is your real intent to run DNS on a low-cost Windows 7/Vista/XP machine?)

Comment: @WhozCraig My intent is to run it on a Windows 7/XP machine and not use Windows Server as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Build-ISC-BIND-DNS-in-Windows) uses the Visual Studio compiler to build the BIND dns server, but from the command line. It does also explain how to correctly compile OpenSSL, which can be quite a pain.

Answer (score 2):

In case no such project exist, it shouldn't be too difficult (although tough) to port a project intended to be built in MinGW to Visual Studio.

Comment: +1 I don't think i would be particularly difficult, honestly, but the again, I avoid MinGW like the plague P

Comment: @WhozCraig why? is mingw that bad??

Comment: @UmNyobe heh. no, I'm just spoiled on VS for a number of years. Of course, the latest VS (2012) kinda blows, imho, and I'm getting back into  closer-to-the-metal tools on my BSD rig, so my opinion is bound to change on that =P